# Unable to undrestand IKVM exception

Tags: exception, ikvm

I have some java code converted to .net assemblies using IKVM.
When ever I run the application, it throws an exception as below:

```
The type initializer for '1' threw an exception.
{"Method not found: 'System.Exception java.lang.Throwable.__<map>(System.Exception, System.Type, Boolean)'."}
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of hours, I could figure out the problem.
The IKVM version that made .net assemblies is important. higher versions which I got from  Nuget did not work properly. I had to download IKVM version 0.42.0.3